# Regexes for modifying beginning and end of line or string

Tags: java, regex

Given this string **1990January20hello.abc** I want to apply regexes to get the final string **1990January-20hello.abc**

I thought I could do:

```
 String text = "1990January20hello.abc";
 Pattern p = Patter.compile("(.*)(January|Jan)(.*)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
 Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
 while (m.find()){
   String val1 = m.group(2);
   String val2 = val1.replace("$", "-");
   text = text.replace(val1, val2);
 }
```

When I do that seems like in the while loop it does find "January" but val2 and text stay January. what am I doing wrong? Its as if Java doesn't recognize $ for end of line/string. Ideally I want to say **val1.replace("(^|$)","-")** so I can get **1990-January-20hello.abc** as final string. Please help. Thanks for suggestions in advance.

Comment: you didn't explain the rule very clearly. the "January" could be "Jan"? or could it be any other string? do you want to add a `-` in front of the 2nd `\d+` ? are there always two set of `\d+`? also, you gave your expected output twice, (at beginning and end of your question), and they are different.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for a pattern:

`(\d+)([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)(.*)`

The resulting groups and their values are:

Group 1 = 1990,
Group 2 = January,
Group 3 = 20,
Group 4 = the rest of the string.

And then you can append them together and add whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

`String#replace` does not use regular expressions so will not match start or end of line characters. You can use one of the replace methods that does use a regular expression such as [replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
String text = "1990January20hello.abc";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*)(January|Jan)(.*)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
while (m.find()) {
   String val1 = m.group(2);
   String val2 = val1.replaceAll("$|^", "-");
   text = text.replace(val1, val2);
}
```

Output:

```
1990-January-20hello.abc
```

Comment: I don't think Strings understand all the regex patterns and so it won't recognize ($|^) pattern. In the while loop I had to use the Pattern/Matcher again and that worked. Posting answer to my question

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String s = "1990January20hello.abc";
String s2 = s.replaceAll("(Jan|January)(\\d+)", "$1-$2");
System.out.println(s2);
```

Or using Matcher

```
String s3 = Pattern
    .compile("(Jan|January)(\\d+)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
    .matcher(s).replaceAll("$1-$2");
System.out.println(s3);
```

Answer (score 0):

String does not recognize all regex patterns and thats why my replace was failing. Heres how I solved it:

```
 String text = "1990January20hello.abc";
 Pattern p = Patter.compile("(.*)(January|Jan)(.*)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
 Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
 while (m.find()){
  String val1 = m.group(2); //"January"
  Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(^|$);
  Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(val1); 
  String val2 = m1.replaceAll("-"); //"-January-"
  text = text.replace(val1, val2); //"1990-January-20hello.abc"
}
```

Thank you for feedback!